# "VBA." prefix, for example VBA.Randomize vs Randomize, what's the difference?

Tags: excel, vba

I've just checked some GitHub code and it was full of statements preceded by "VBA.", which work just fine without it.

What's the reason behind adding "VBA."?

Comment: Is is useful if your environment includes several sources for the functions.  It also removes ambiguities like`TRIM()` vs `Application.Trim()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

VBA is a reference library which tells the compiler to specifically use the VBA-specific implementation of the method or function which follows.

The reason for this is because there might be other referenced libraries which might have priority by default, and the coder does not know what references you might have or in which order they are.

If you had some other implementation of Randomize and it was higher-up in the order of references, the compiler would expect the parameters to match that particular implementation's format and also use that particular bit of code.

Placing `VBA.` in front of VBA keywords merely ensures that the version that will be used is the one that the author intended and not some other version.

Answer (score 4):

Just one way to make totally sure that if anyone has the very bad idea to use `Randomize` as a user defined function/procedure name like:

```
Public Sub Randomize()
    'do fancy stuff
End Sub
```

That `VBA.Randomize` will still call the correct function and not the user defined.